# Can we setup a local HTTPS Server in Mac OS X using swift

Tags: macos, webserver, http

I want to setup a local HTTP Server running in my Mac OSX machine which should be able to handle requests that are coming from web browser. But I am not sure whether we can setup HTTPS server using swift. In this https://swift.org/server-apis/ there is only info about HTTP but not HTTPS. Any help is very much appreciated

Comment: Does it have to be written in Swift? Are you developing or writing the code yourselves?

Comment: Yes it has to be written in swift. I want to write it myself

Comment: Please be aware that code level questions are off-topic here and should be asked on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, Apple's Swift language can be used to create a web server that accepts HTTPS connections. See [Going Server-side with Swift Open Source](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/415/) for Apple's introduction to developing servers.

Using Swift, you have access to a range of included and third party SSL/TLS libraries. The language used to write the library is not important, so long as the library offers a C API.

## Network.framework and AFNetworking

If you are a developer, consider using Apple's [Network framework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/network). The framework claims to provide easier support for secure connections.

Alternatively, look at using the open source project [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking).

### Apple's Frameworks

Given you want to focus on [Apple's security offerings](https://developer.apple.com/security/), you can pick from:

- Apple's Network.framework (in beta at the time of answering)
- Apple's NSURL* family of classes
- Apple's CFNetwork
- Apple's Secure Transport API

Be aware that most of these are ultimately built upon the low level [Common Crypto](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Security/Conceptual/cryptoservices/Introduction/Introduction.html) code base.

### Transparent Proxy

Consider using an existing web server, such as Nginx, httpd, or Caddy, to act as a transparent proxy in-front of your own service. The existing web server can handle the SSL/TLS security and pass back HTTP requests to your locally running service.

This is a fairly common configuration because it simplifies your service and puts the security burden on a well tested existing front-end server.

### Not a developer?

If you are not a developer, consider using a pre-built web server with support for Lets Encrypt (free) TLS certificates. One such server is Caddy:

> [Caddy](https://caddyserver.com) is the HTTP/2 web server with automatic HTTPS.

Comment: I don't want to relay on third party libraries that were mentioned in  (Going Server-side with Swift Open Source). I want to setup it using native swift code. I will try using AFNetworking. Thank you